# The phenomenon of walking backwards to remember a lost thought

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, psychology

I used to have "senior moments" long before I actually became a senior, such as walking from one room to another and forgetting what I was...

An older friend advised me that in moments like these I should  go backwards and catch the moment in which you lost the thought. Her suggestion seemed to mean actually walking backwards...careful that step. But since then, I have found that while thinking back in time can help,  just walking back in your steps slowly to the actual physical location where you lost the thought will bring the thought back.

It's the opposite of Déjà vu.

Déjà vu implies a circular short circuit of the brain.

You cannot control Déjà vu.

Is there a name for this phenomenon?

Comment: I find that you’re not really trying to remember the lost thought you’re trying to re-derive the thought by recreating the situation in which you originally had it.

Comment: This has no connection at all to this web site.  Ask on, say, the Writing SE site for a way to describe this.   For example, *"unwind your recent steps*" or maybe *"walk backwards"*.

Answer (score 8):

I'm having difficulty finding more convincing supporting evidence, but I'm happy with the content. From [HiNative](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/15533362) (amended):

> - Can **retrace your steps** have a figurative meaning? [nuriavivo ]
> - Yes. You could say: *I thought about my day [...] I retraced my steps*.
>
> You didn't physically go back and walk through your day all over [...]
> you 'walked through your mind' to replay your day.  [SCLCJ]
>
> - Yes, it means to remember what you did earlier. Usually so that you can remember where you put your keys (or any other lost object).
>   [Chook 15]

Here is a quote from a novel, the figurative use forced by the *phase* ('sit knitting') *construction*:

> - *He sat retracing his steps and that's when it hit him ....*

[[G Lusby: *Serial*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=x7ob7KsgRssC&pg=PT132&lpg=PT132&dq=%22sat+retracing+his+steps%22&source=bl&ots=XDIDNdqDDY&sig=ACfU3U1eoPkO5t_xnZzDzkbbA7eHAPNg2g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiehrj5mfbtAhWtWhUIHXJzCIMQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22sat%20retracing%20his%20steps%22&f=false)]

No doubt **backtrack** can be used in a similar way, but care needs to be exercised in utilising this sense; the default figurative sense (listed first by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/backtrack) and Macmillan) is 'to withdraw from an undertaking / stance ...'.

Comment: Excellent answer, I was going to indicate the same expression. Though "retracing one's steps" is usually defined by dictionaries as a physical action, it can be used figuratively. The same goes for some of this expression's [synonyms](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/retrace_your_steps.html).

Comment: Yes. One reason retracing helps is that if in the bedroom you realized you needed something from the kitchen, going back to the bedroom will trigger the reason anew.

Comment: For the record, *retracing your steps* is *repeating* in the *same order as before*.  (You've walked from the kitchen to the lounge room.  Hercule Poirot makes you *retrace your stepss* - to wit, by ........ doing that again.  Retracing ... your steps.) It is literally absolutely the exact opposite of what is being asked.

Comment: Not according to [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retrace), @Fattie. << **retrace** [transitive verb]: to trace (something) again or back: such as
**a**: to go over or along (something, such as a course or path) again often in a reverse direction ... >>

Answer (score 3):

Here's a scientific fact: Walking through doorways causes forgetting.<sup>1</sup>

Psychologists call this phenomenon the "doorway effect." Your small notion to, for example, go to the kitchen for a vitamin is apt to get cleared from your working memory buffer as you experience an "event boundary"—the literal passing through a doorway here—and your brain prepares to handle new information.

Though there is plenty of anecdotal evidence that returning to the room you came from can jog your memory, research shows that the notion of "[context-dependent memory](https://www.alleydog.com/glossary/definition.php?term=Context%2520Dependent%2520Memory)" does not play out in this situation.<sup>2</sup>

***Maybe that's why this room-return-memory-jog phenomenon doesn't have a name.***

Whether it's real or not, I'd be quite surprised if walking backwards yielded any better results than turning around and walking forward—at any speed.

***In the meantime, maybe we can just call it . . . a do-over.***<sup>3</sup>

<sub>1 [How walking through a door wipes your memory](https://blogs.unimelb.edu.au/sciencecommunication/2016/09/07/how-walking-through-a-door-wipes-your-memory/)

2 [Walking through doorways causes forgetting: Further explorations](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21563019/)

3 [Just for fun](https://ifunny.co/video/when-yo-walk-into-a-room-but-immediately-forgetw-y-cjYfvJ335)</sub>